# Sonata Admin sonata_type_collection not remove child entity

Tags: symfony, one-to-many, sonata-admin

I have a News Entity with "One To Many" association with a Image Entity:

```
class Noticia 
{

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ImagemNoticia", mappedBy="noticia", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $images;

    public function removeImage(ImagemNoticia $imagem) {
        if ($this->images->contains($imagem) {
            $this->images->removeElement($imagem);
        }
        $imagem->setNoticia(null);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And a Admin Class:

```
class NoticiaAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
         $formMapper
             ->add('images', 'sonata_type_collection', 
                  array(
                      'by_reference' => false,
                      'required' => false, 
                  ), array(
                      'edit' => 'inline'
                      'inline' => 'table'
                  )
              );
    }
}
```

Inserting and Updating images works perfectly.

When I mark "Delete" in a Image on embeded form and save the entity association field is removed from ImagemNoticia Entity but this entity is not removed

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

PS:
In NoticiaAdmin I have:

```
public function preUpdate($object)
{
    foreach ($object->getImagens() as $imagem) {
        $imagem->setNoticia($object);
    }
    parent::preUpdate($object);
}
```

and ImagemNoticiaAdmin is:

```
class ImagemNoticiaAdmin extends Admin {

    /**
     * @param FormMapper $formMapper
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $imagemNoticia = $this->getSubject();
        if ($imagemNoticia) {
            $formMapper->add(
                'file',
                'liip_imagine_image',
                [
                    'image_path' => $imagemNoticia->getWebPath(),
                    'image_filter' => 'noticia_thumb',
                ]
            );
        } else {
            $formMapper->add(
                'file',
                'file'
            );
        }
        $formMapper
            ->add(
                'flag',
                'choice',
                [
                    'choices' => ImagemNoticia::getFlags(),
                    'label' => 'Tipo'
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'legenda',
                null,
                [
                    'required' => false,
                ]
            );
    } 
}
```

Comment: Do you have an Admin class for ImagemNoticia? If you have, copy paste it, please. And try to use preUpdate().

Comment: 2I forgot to mention that: yes, I have Admin class to ImagemNoticia, and already use preUpdate

Comment: @maches: I edited my question to include preUpdate e ImagemNoticiaAdmin class

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this annotation which specify that column referenced with that noticia id need to be deleted :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ImagemNoticia", mappedBy="noticia", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="noticia_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */

private $images;
```

Comment: Far as I know `onDelete="CASCADE"` is for the "child" side of relation (Many-To-One) and deletes all ImagemNoticia entities IF I delete Noticia entity related to those

Comment: isnt that what you wanted? removing the imagenoticia relation with noticia entity on delete?

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself.

I disable APC doctrine metadata_cache_driver and run "console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata"

Comment: really? Becuase i would have thought that this in the admin  `'by_reference' => false,` means the references in the database are not taken into account.